# Office Online Server / Office Web Apps Server - How to test?

Tags: office-web-apps

When I´m installing a Office Online Server 2016. How can I validate that everything is green before adding the Server to SharePoint, Exchange etc?

With the Office Web Apps Server 2013 it was possible to open the URL http(s)://Server/op/generate.aspx and use the webinterface from the OWS to open a document in the browser.

I know there is also the URL http(s)://Server/hosting/discovery with a XML output, but this is not really a test for me.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The real testing can only be done after configuring the host.

Answer (score 3):

> After the farm is created, details about the farm are displayed in the Windows PowerShell prompt. To verify that Office Web Apps Server is installed and configured correctly, use a web browser to access the Office Web Apps Server discovery URL, as shown in the following example. The discovery URL is the InternalUrl parameter you specified when you configured your Office Web Apps Server farm, followed by /hosting/discovery, for example:

```
http://servername/hosting/discovery
```

> If Office Web Apps Server is working as expected, you should see a Web Application Open Platform Interface Protocol (WOPI)-discovery XML file in your web browser. The first few lines of that file should resemble the following example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <wopi-discovery>
- <net-zone name="internal-http">
- <app name="Excel" favIconUrl="http://servername/x/_layouts/images/FavIcon_Excel.ico" checkLicense="true">
<action name="view" ext="ods" default="true" urlsrc="http://servername/x/_layouts/xlviewerinternal.aspx?<ui=UI_LLCC&><rs=DC_LLCC&>" /> 
<action name="view" ext="xls" default="true" urlsrc="http://servername/x/_layouts/xlviewerinternal.aspx?<ui=UI_LLCC&>        <rs=DC_LLCC&>" /> 
<action name="view" ext="xlsb" default="true" urlsrc="http://servername/x/_layouts/xlviewerinternal.aspx?<ui=UI_LLCC&><rs=DC_LLCC&>" /> 
<action name="view" ext="xlsm" default="true" urlsrc="http://servername/x/_layouts/xlviewerinternal.aspx?<ui=UI_LLCC&><rs=DC_LLCC&>" />
```

Comment: Hello Amal, I know that I can open the discovery xml (As I had already written). But this is not a valid test in my eyes.

Comment: As per Microsoft at this point you can assume the Office Online is installed properly.

Comment: you can also compare with the online version: https://broadcast.officeapps.live.com/hosting/discovery

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled accross the same issue, also for me the "discovery XML file" does not imply that the my documents are accessible. For example:

```
Can not create an identity context for system account user token.
```

This, for example, happens when you access the file with a system account.
But there is an option to check this.

In the "Document Library" (viewed with the "SharePoint Classic View"), click the three dots and you will get the WOPI Frame preview. With the link to share the document, you will get redirected to URL using a WOPI Frame that displays the document:

```
http://servername/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=identifier+filename.pdf&action=default
```

In my case, the discovery with

```
http://servername/hosting/discovery
```

showed that everything is correct, but the WOPI Frame raised an error.
Only after checking this, the Office Web App Server works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In the link which you posted it states that you can test OWA and OOS servers, you can try.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/administration/test-viewing-documents-by-using-office-online-server-viewer